# Asp.net WebForm Web API version handling using namespace and persist old API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a asp.net WebForm project that contain Web Api v2. I didn't consider api versioning and add my whole api with simple route below:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
);
```

But, now, I need to create versioning because I have lots of change and don't want to disappoint my older client which use old api. So I create a new folder called APIv2 and create my controller there (which has the same name as the old api). The problem is how could I route something like this :

```
MyWebsite/API/Item => For ItemController OF OLD API
MyWebsite/APIv2/Item => For ItemController Of New API (Version 2)
```

I've read lots of post but none of them work for me ! Also I create NamespaceHttpControllerSelector, But it doesn't work too.

please give me some example of how to handle this.

P.S : when I create simple routing such as the old one for new api, it says duplicate controller found ! (Although I am using different namespace)

Edit (Add My Complete Code) :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new NamespaceHttpControllerSelector(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));

        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "VersionedApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/v2/{controller}");

        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}");
```

And the NamespaceHttpControllerSelector:

```
public class NamespaceHttpControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
    private const string ControllerKey = "controller";
    private readonly HttpConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly Lazy<IEnumerable<Type>> _duplicateControllerTypes;

    public NamespaceHttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _duplicateControllerTypes = new Lazy<IEnumerable<Type>>(GetDuplicateControllerTypes);
    }

    public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var routeData = request.GetRouteData();
        if (routeData == null || routeData.Route == null || routeData.Route.DataTokens == null || routeData.Route.DataTokens["Namespaces"] == null) 
            return base.SelectController(request);

        // Look up controller in route data
        object controllerName;
        routeData.Values.TryGetValue(ControllerKey, out controllerName);
        var controllerNameAsString = controllerName as string;
        if (controllerNameAsString == null) 
            return base.SelectController(request);

        //get the currently cached default controllers - this will not contain duplicate controllers found so if
        // this controller is found in the underlying cache we don't need to do anything
        var map = base.GetControllerMapping();
        if (map.ContainsKey(controllerNameAsString)) 
            return base.SelectController(request);

        //the cache does not contain this controller because it's most likely a duplicate, 
        // so we need to sort this out ourselves and we can only do that if the namespace token
        // is formatted correctly.
        var namespaces = routeData.Route.DataTokens["Namespaces"] as IEnumerable<string>;
        if (namespaces == null)
            return base.SelectController(request);

        //see if this is in our cache
        var found = _duplicateControllerTypes.Value
            .Where(x => string.Equals(x.Name, controllerNameAsString + ControllerSuffix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .FirstOrDefault(x => namespaces.Contains(x.Namespace));

        if (found == null)
            return base.SelectController(request);

        return new HttpControllerDescriptor(_configuration, controllerNameAsString, found);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Type> GetDuplicateControllerTypes()
    {
        var assembliesResolver = _configuration.Services.GetAssembliesResolver();
        var controllersResolver = _configuration.Services.GetHttpControllerTypeResolver();
        var controllerTypes = controllersResolver.GetControllerTypes(assembliesResolver);

        //we have all controller types, so just store the ones with duplicate class names - we don't
        // want to cache too much and the underlying selector caches everything else

        var duplicates = controllerTypes.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .ToArray();

        return duplicates;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/08/using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis.aspx)? You mention `NamespaceHttpControllerSelector`, is it from there? Please post your complete code regarding WebAPI configuration.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev I read that article and another one, both doesn't work ! I also Edit post and post my complete code (Last version so far).

Comment: What exactly does not work if you do according to the article?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev I get this error : The request for 'item' has found the following matching controllers: Pooshanet.API.v2.ItemController Pooshanet.API.ItemController, may it be because of the namespace it self?

Comment: Are you sure you're referring to the article I've linked above, not the code you've posted? They are different.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev I mention that I use two different code, the one you refer and the one I post ! both doesn't work, but I check your link one more time for sure, tnx

Comment: @SergRogovtsev I check it and use [this custom class](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/dd207952fa86#Samples/WebApi/NamespaceControllerSelector/NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.cs), I got no error now, but no result too ! I just get and empty screen !!! (I should mention API is correct and return well when there is no version)

Comment: The class you're mentioning requires a particular setup of routing and namespaces (that is not exactly compatible with your case).

Comment: @SergRogovtsev the first if cause exception in my code ! (because there is no DataToken) I change it, and now your code work, thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to just add `NamespaceHttpControllerSelector`, you have to provide data for it.

This line

```
var namespaces = routeData.Route.DataTokens["Namespaces"] as IEnumerable<string>;
```

tells that it is expecting a list of namespaces to look for controller in a data token called "Namespaces". But the thing is, there's no easy way to set DataTokens in WebAPI (they are originally from MVC), so we'll have to change the code.

Replace

```
//the cache does not contain this controller because it's most likely a duplicate, 
// so we need to sort this out ourselves and we can only do that if the namespace token
// is formatted correctly.
var namespaces = routeData.Route.DataTokens["Namespaces"] as IEnumerable<string>;
if (namespaces == null)
  return base.SelectController(request);

//see if this is in our cache
var found = _duplicateControllerTypes.Value
  .Where(x => string.Equals(x.Name, controllerNameAsString + ControllerSuffix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  .FirstOrDefault(x => namespaces.Contains(x.Namespace));
```

with

```
var @namespace = routeData.Values["namespace"] as string;
if (@namespace == null)
  return base.SelectController(request);

//see if this is in our cache
var found = _duplicateControllerTypes.Value
  .Where(x => string.Equals(x.Name, controllerNameAsString + ControllerSuffix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Namespace == @namespace);
```

And change your routing as follows:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "VersionedApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/v2/{controller}",
  defaults: new {@namespace = "your namespace for v2 controllers"}
);

RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
  defaults: new {@namespace = "your namespace for v1 controllers"}
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I again cause Duplicate error and says : The request for 'item' has found the following matching controllers: Pooshanet.API.v2.ItemController Pooshanet.API.ItemController, may it be because of the namespace it self? (Also I change your code to new string[]{"my namespace name"}, yours cause error)

Comment: Oh, I see, your controller selector relied on DataTokens. Updated the answer.

Comment: Same error again ! (namespace is a keyword change it with namespaces in your code)

Comment: Updated the code in answer again (sorry, it is hard to program in text editor).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Web Api attribute routing.

```
public ItemControllerV2 : ApiController
{
    [Route("v2/item/{id:int}")]
    public Item Get(int id)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Also remember to enable attribute routing in your Web Api configuration

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        //rest of your Web Api configuration
    }
 }
```

More information about attribute routing you can find here : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

---

**EDIT**

If as you wrote in comment, you have many method in controller and you don't want to add attribute to every method you can use `RoutePrefix` attribute :

```
[RoutePrefix("v2/item")]
public ItemControllerV2 : ApiController
{
}
```

> Also I don't have WebApiConfig file, where should I create it ?

It is the same place where you have that method invocation:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
);
```

So, in this place you must add following method invocation to enable attribute routing :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config => 
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
    );
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but, there is lots of method, should I add it for all of them? is there anyway to just separate all together? Also I don't have WebApiConfig file, where should I create it ?

Comment: Thanks again, Actually I don't have WebApiConfig file, I add the route part in my Global.asax (Application_Start method) !

Comment: I see. Particularly it isn't wrong to have all configuration directly in `Application_Start` method. But if your project grows it can benefit from separating various elements configurations to separate classes. You further use this classes in `Application_Start` method, but thanks to that it becomes more maintainable.

Comment: There is no "config" in Application_Start to use ! I add this 
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); in Session_Start (In Application_Start it cause error), but nothing change !

Comment: You're right It was my mistake that I assumed that you used default template for configuring WebApi. I corrected the invocation for enabling attribute routing.  Anyway, you should put it in `Application_Start`. What error you got when you use it in `Application_Start`?

Comment: Thanks for your helping, I get this error : The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's startup code after all other initialization code. (Although It is the first line of Application_Start) ....

Comment: Ok, I know where is the problem, I corrected the method invocation for enabling attribute routing. You can check it now.

Comment: It cause this error again : Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'item'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('api/v2/{controller}') found multiple controllers defined with the same name but differing namespaces, which is not supported.

Comment: If you use approach with `Attribute Routing` you shouldn't use replace `IHttpControllerSelector` with `NamespaceHttpControllerSelector` in configuration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90609/discussion-between-arkadiusz-k-and-evil).